# Get clientside Date and Time format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I want is, the formatted string as, `MM/DD/YY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`.
Which of these is set by client in his/her system.
How to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: What do you mean by `get client time format`? Provide some example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();

var final = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
console.log(final); // "1/11/2015"
```

http://jsbin.com/zixacacuda/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

```
 var dt=new Date('2015-12-12'); 
    var d=dt.getDay();
    var m=dt.getMonth();
    var y=dt.getFullYear();
    var dtformated=d+'/'+m+'/'+y
    console.log(dtformated)
```

Answer (score 0):

var now = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

it willl retrun "12/28/2015 (MM/DD/YYYY)" format.